# Find number of numerical digits in all possible hexadecimal numbers of length n

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As stated in question, find number of digits in all possible hexadecimal numbers of length n.

If n = 1; out of 1 to F we have 9 ( exclude digits starting with 0 ) If n = 2; 11 to 1F - we have 26 digits and so on..

There seems to be a pattern that i was unable to formulate.

If we consider hexadecimal numbers of length 1 we need to exclude 0 and start from 1 to F ( each of 1 to 9 have 1 digit and none from A to F have any digits in it ) if we check from 10 to 1F ( each number from 10 to 19 has two digits in it and each number from 1A to 1F have 1 digit in it )

Comment: You've got it wrong for $n=2$...

Comment: Are you asking for the number of unique hexidecimal numbers of length $n$?

Comment: I don't follow the first remark which gives a count of nine "excluding digits starting with 0".  There are sixteen hexadecimal place values, so after excluding zero as a leading digit, there are fifteen possible leading digits.

Comment: If we consider hexadecimal numbers of length 1 we need to exclude 0 and start from 1 to F ( each of 1 to 9 have 1 digit and none from A to F have any digits in it )

if we check from 10 to 1F ( each number from 10 to 19 has two digits in it and each number from 1A to 1F have 1 digit in it )

Answer (score 1):

There are $15\cdot16^{n-1}$ numbers having $n$ hexadecimal digits. At the first place ${9\over15}$ of these have a numerical digit, and at the following $n-1$ places ${10\over16}$ of these have a numerical digit.
It follows that the number $N_n$ you are after is given by
$$N_n=15\cdot 16^{n-1}\left({9\over15}+(n-1){10\over16}\right)\ .$$

Comment: For two-digit hexadecimal numbers there are $9\cdot10=90$ with $2$ numerical digits, $9\cdot6=54$ of the form '1A', and $6\cdot10=60$ of the form 'A0', for a total of $90\cdot2+54+60=294$ total numerical digits. Your fomula gives only $288$

Comment: @DanielMathias: Thank you for reporting the mistake. I had not correctly handled the difficulties arising from the first digit.

Comment: Your solution now matches mine. The same can be expressed as $16^{n-2}(150n-6)$